# Fail to filtering Spam Referal in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I see a lot of spam referal in my google analytics... so  I'm creating new custom filter and exclude 'hostname' field, with this regex pattern: 
`.*best\-seo\-(offer|solution)\.com|buttons\-for\-your\-website\.com`

but somehow those referal still coming up! probably something wrong with my regex pattern eventhough i already validate it through regexpal.com

Any insight ?

Comment: What are some of the strings you think should match this regexp and don't?

Comment: Here's some hostname exported:
best-seo-offer.com and
buttons-for-you-website.com

Comment: You need to group the `or` I think, I'm not sure where you are using this regex though. Also `-` doesn't need to be escaped. So maybe `.*(best-seo-(offer|solution)|buttons-for-your-website)\.com`?

Comment: You can find more details about this in this blog post: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Filtering by hostname will only exclude sessions that occur on domains that have the same GA tracking code on their domain as yours. See the [hostname custom report as example](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=aAIc0-9dTz-3VC9uJ_QBSw).</strike>

Instead you could exclude this referral traffic by adding the spam domains to the *referral exclusion list* (Admin > Property > Tracking Info > Referral Exclusion List.) Unfortunately, you can't add a regex: you have to enter each domain separately. More info on the [Referral Exclusion List](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en).

This [custom report](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/template?uid=O351wxXBQCC0U-49YTArGw) could give you a list of spam domains to exclude.

UPDATE: I've changed my answer as my previous answer would inflate direct traffic.

You should filter out Referrals instead of Hostname to exclude this spam referral traffic. When creating a filter, make sure you always have a view that has no filters on. Here's how to create the filter:

1. Admin > View > Filters
2. + New Filter
3. Filter Type == Custom
4. Exclude, Filter Field == Referral

[More info in this article](https://megalytic.com/blog/how-to-filter-out-fake-referrals-and-other-google-analytics-spam).

Comment: as far as i know....adding hostname to Referral Exclusion List will make the referral from domain spammer count as direct traffic